# Invalid System.Uri parsing under NUnit

Tags: c#, .net, nunit

Reproduced under ReSharper, from GUI-Runner, from NUnit-Console

Tested on :

Win 7 Pro, all updates, Ru-ru locale - reproduced

Win Server 2012, all updates En-us locale - reproduced

Try this:

```
[TestFixture(Description = "Uri .ctors under Nunit must work exactly as no under Nunit")]
public class InvalidUriCtorUnderNnit
{
    [Test]
    public void PathsWithDotsMustBeParsedWell()
    {
        const string urlWithDots = "http://host.com/path./";
        Assert.AreEqual(urlWithDots, new Uri(urlWithDots).ToString());
    }
}
```

Expected:

> Uri not changed and "http://host.com/path./" returned

Actual:

> Cropped  "http://host.com/path/" returned

Notes:

1. It's broken, while cropped Uri not matched required resource
2. This behavior never occured in production and cannot be catched except under NUNIT run.
3. Have compared all loaded assemblies versions and codebase - all exactly match with production
4. Have tested Internet on this issue - nothing

Wish you could reproduce.

NUnit version 2.6.2 and 2.6.3 have same behavior.

Have posted us issue to  https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/237

Comment: Can you explain what behaviour you see and what you expected ?

Comment: Instead of "http://host.com/path./" it returns "http://host.com/path/", had improved question

Answer (score 3):

Guys from NUnit check it and founs that it's one of broken changes of .NET 4.5, so if NUnit will be rebuilt targeting this version all will be fine. Uri normalization was a feature-like-bug of all versions of .net before and it was my luck that i have just met it...