# Nunit: Special character in uri

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, uri, uribuilder

I have a weird problem.

```
var dummyUri = new UriBuilder("http", "localhost", 8585, "Some[Name");
```

If I put this code block to console app , absolute uri will be displayed like following.

AbsoluteUri = "http://localhost:8585/Some[Name"

If I put this code block in my test class(that means i am using nunit), absoluteUri will be displayed like following.

AbsoluteUri = "http://localhost:8585/Some%5BName"

And I am wondering that what is the differences.

Comment: Whenever i run this test with Reharper, It seems it is working. but whenever I run this test with Nunit GUI, it is failing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25968963/invalid-system-uri-parsing-under-nunit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find same question and solution for this problem [here](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues/237)